# Python: Iterate and Print Integer

Tags: python

In Java, we can do something like:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 10)
   System.out.println(i++);
```

where it iterates `i` and prints it. Can the same be done in python?

**EDIT:**
Specifically, I'd like to do something like:

```
words = ["red","green","blue"]
current_state = 0
for word in words:
  for char in word:
     print(char,current_state,current_state+1)

Result
r 0 1
e 1 2
d 2 3
g 3 4
r 4 5
e 5 6
....
```

Comment: why not use `range` `for x in range(9):print x+1`?

Comment: This won't work for my specific problem. But thanks

Comment: You should add what you are trying to do as it does exactly what you are asking

Comment: Thanks, I added a more specific example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the equivalent of the `++` operator in Java, the answer is no.  Python requires you to do:

```
i += 1
```

on its own line.

However, you may be looking for [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), which allows you to keep track of what index you are at while iterating over a container:

```
>>> for i, j in enumerate(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']):
...     print(i, j)
...
0 a
1 b
2 c
3 d
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i = 0
while i < 10:
    i += 1
    print i
```

Comment: I think OP meant to do this at the same time, but this solution is better and more clear.